# I got error getting current url by its name in AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 9 site Inside of boot method of AppServiceProvider I try to get current url(by its name) as :

```
$currentURL = URL::current();
        \Log::info( $currentURL );
        \Log::info( Request::url() );
// lines above works ok


        \Log::info( Route::current() );
// the line above returns null

// and error  on next line :
Call to a member function getName() on null
```

on next line :

```
    \Log::info(Route::current()->getName());
```

Why  function getName does not work in this case and how that can be fixed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because it is null. Route class will not work in the AppServiceProvider since it's not resolved yet.

Comment: the Request hasn't been dispatched to the router at this point so there won't be a current route yet